# Can xtext be used as an expression language within Java?

Tags: java, dsl, xtext

We are considering using xtext to develop a DSL that could be used to simplify some complex logic and query operations, but would like to use it in-place, within a Java class. Can this be done?

What we want is to use it to develop something almost like LINQ, but useable within Java. All examples that I have seen of xtext generate .java classes from the DSL, which is great, but not exactly what we want here.

So, something like:

`List<ICreature> dragons = dataEngine.parse(get Monster where Type = Dragon and HitPoints > 1000);`

I believe we *could* do this if the queries were pre-written in a separate query file, and then compiled via the xtext generator into a form that could be passed to our data management layer, but we want something more flexible than that.

xText looked promising, but it seems likely we'll end up using [jOOQ](http://www.jooq.org/) or something like it instead of a true DSL.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, unfortunately neither Eclipse's Java editor nor the java parser and compiler allow to hook in such that this would be possible. With Xbase you can embed Java-like expressions and statements in your DSL, but the other way round is not supported.

Comment: This would be such a killer feature for the whole Xtext stack, in my opinion! Too bad :-)

Answer (score 1):

> but it seems likely we'll end up using [jOOQ](http://www.jooq.org) or something like it instead of a true DSL.

jOOQ *is* a true DSL :-) A true [internal domain specific language](http://www.infoq.com/articles/internal-dsls-java), as opposed to an [external DSL](http://javieracero.com/blog/internal-vs-external-dsl). As a matter of fact, I've been looking into [Xtend](http://www.eclipse.org/xtend/) / [Xtext](http://www.eclipse.org/Xtext/) recently to see if jOOQ itself could be enhanced to make it look less like Java and more like SQL, by defining an actual grammar for parsing SQL statements and transforming them into jOOQ calls.

This seems to be possible with a technology called [Xbase](http://wiki.eclipse.org/Xbase), created by the same guys as the aforementioned Xtend and Xtext. In fact, the Xtend language is based on Xbase. According to their documentation, this will allow you to integrate your own grammar into something that almost looks like Java, and thus to define interaction patterns between Java and your own DSL.

I didn't succeed in understanding their documentation so far, but maybe you could get some help [on their forum](http://www.eclipse.org/forums/index.php?t=thread&frm_id=27)?